# C# - Read DocumentPrivilege properties from a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose

I am using Aspose library to read, open and save pdf file.
I am looking the way to get the security value of a pdf file from the property "AllowModifyContents".

This is how it is set:

```
            using (var documenttosecure = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(inputFilePath))
            {
                using (var pdfOutput = new PdfFileSecurity(documenttosecure))
                {
                    var docP = DocumentPrivilege.AllowAll;

                    docP.AllowPrint = true;
                    docP.AllowCopy = true;
                    docP.AllowModifyContents = false;

                    pdfOutput.SetPrivilege(docP);

                    documenttosecure.Save(outputFile);
                }
            }
```

Now I need to get that pdf and find the property AllowModifyContents  from the pdf DocumentPrivilege.

Do you know how to read that property value?

Thanks for your help;
Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetDocumentPrivilege()` method of `Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfFileInfo` class, returns an object of type `DocumentPrivilege`, through which you can determine the value of `AllowModifyContents` property. Please check following code snippet, in order to achieve your requirement.

```
// Instantiate PdfFileInfo Class object.
Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfFileInfo info = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfFileInfo();
// Load your encrypted PDF document.
info.BindPdf(dataDir + "EncryptedDocument.pdf");
// Get DocumentPrivilege
Facades.DocumentPrivilege documentPrivilege = info.GetDocumentPrivilege();
// Determine AllowModifyContents
bool AllowModifyContents = documentPrivilege.AllowModifyContents;
```

*Note: I am Asad Ali and work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.*

Comment: Yes. That is what I was looking for and it works perfectly.

Thank you very much Asad Ali